# Physical Lethargy

Tags: meditation

I've read about the existence of mental lethargy, and have experienced it for myself. But, when it comes to physical lethargy, is there any meditative practice that counters it? Also, I'm saying this especially in relationship to willpower (avoiding attachment activities) and effort (practicing aversive activities). Ideally, I'm looking for the best practices to counter these things, and ultimately have more energy, willpower and effort in the day.

While we're at it, can anyone give me their opinions on activities which involve attachment but which aren't necessarily so for everyone, e.g. facebook and junk food. These activities, in me, seem to create a strong attachment and consequently I'm trying to rid myself of them, but keep experiencing a failure of willpower and determination.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Physical lethargy is not really a problem as long as your mind stays unaffected. But in reality physical lethargy most of the time comes with mental lethargy. There are already lots of answers regarding the 3. hindrance on this SE.

- [Ways of Raising Energy](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/18253/ways-of-raising-energy)
- [Clarity During Meditation](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/9970/clarity-during-meditation)
- [Sloth-torpor-Restlessness-worry](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3485/sloth-torpor-restlessness-worry/3523#3523)

Also see: [The Five Mental Hindrances and Their Conquest](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nyanaponika/wheel026.html)

As for "bad habits" IMO the best way to deal with them is to be patient. Using willpower and trying to changes things is often a guarantee for more feelings of guilt, failure and suffering. Instead of trying to get rid of you could develop wholesome habits (meditation, sati, virtue of action, speech and thought ...) alongside the bad ones and then step by step replace old habits with new ones.