# Why my Mind told me to Sleep?

Tags: the-buddha, vipassana

I have observed one thing, when i meditated first time Vipassana last week, i saw vibrations in my body, but after that day its been many days i have not seen them, in-fact i can not sit for long  (only 15-20 minutes), its not that my legs hurt,

But its my mind, it says “Why are you doing this, lets sleep, when i tell it no, it says its more comfortable to meditate in sleep”.
and then i sleep, How do i control it, am i missing something ?

Comment: There are good answers regarding this topic at https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/8889/being-present-with-the-help-of-body-sensations-then-how-to-proceed/8894#8894 or https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3485/sloth-torpor-restlessness-worry/3523#3523

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i saw vibrations in my body, but after that day its been many days i have not seen them

When you experience something like vibration you should understand this is also not permanent. You should not crave to experience it again.

This craving can also lead to arising of [hindrances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_hindrances).

> But its my mind, it says “Why are you doing this, lets sleep, when i tell it no, it says its more comfortable to meditate in sleep”. and then i sleep, How do i control it, am i missing something ?

This can be either you being merely lazy and trying to find and excuse to doze off or [sloth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thina) and [torpor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middha) taking its hold. Whenever, you experience something like vibration this stirs up deep rooted [Saṅkhāra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sa%E1%B9%85kh%C4%81ra) which might manifest itself like aches and pains or hindrances.

Sloth and torpor is nourished  by unwise attention, you should denourish it by [wise attention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampaja%C3%B1%C3%B1a) and [exertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C4%ABrya). Also see [The Five Mental Hindrances and Their Conquest: Selected Texts from the Pali Canon and the Commentaries](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nyanaponika/wheel026.html) compiled and translated by Nyanaponika Thera and also [Pacalā Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/4.11-Pacala-S-a7.58-piya.pdf) which deals with dozing off. Also there are many answers, which I have given, which deal with Pacalā Sutta which which are listed [here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=Pacal%C4%81+Sutta+user%3A295) and relevant to this context and also [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/3487/295). Also more content may be tagged [meditation-hindrances](/questions/tagged/meditation-hindrances) and [five-hindrances](/questions/tagged/five-hindrances) which are also relevant. Content I have created under the above tags are found [here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmeditation-hindrances%5D%20user%3A295) and [here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfive-hindrances%5D%20user%3A295) which might be less noisy and more relevant. Also [Nīvaraṇa](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/32.1-Nivarana.-piya.pdf), [Thīna,middha](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/32.6-Thinamiddha-piya.pdf) by Piya Tan might be useful.

The Vipassana method, as in the [Pacalā Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/4.11-Pacala-S-a7.58-piya.pdf), is as follow:

> > **“Nothing is worth clinging to”**
> >
> > When this was said, the venerable Mahā Moggallāna said this to the Blessed One:
> >     “In what way, bhante, in brief, is a monk freed through the destruction of craving, that is, one who has reached total perfection, the total security from bondage, the total holy life, the total consummation, the highest amongst gods and humans?”
> >
> > “Here, Moggallāna, the monk has learned that nothing is worth clinging to.
> >     And, Moggallāna, a monk has learned that nothing is worth clinging to, thus: he directly knows all things [he directly knows the nature of the all].
> >     Having **directly known the nature of all things**, he **fully understands all
> >     things**.
> >
> > Having **fully understood all things**, he knows ***whatever feelings there are***, whether ***pleasant, painful or neither painful nor pleasant***.
> >
> > **As regards to those *feelings***, *[Section on [Disillusionment and Revulsion (Nibbida)](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/20.1-Nibbida-piya.pdf) follows]*
> >
> > he dwells contemplating *impermanence* in them;
> >
> > he dwells contemplating *dispassion* [fading away of lust] in them;
> >
> > he dwells contemplating *ending* (of suffering) in them;
> >
> > he dwells contemplating *letting go* (of defilements).
> >
> > ***When he dwells*** contemplating *impermanence* in them, contemplating *dispassion* in them, contemplating *ending* in them, contemplating *letting go*, he ***does not cling to anything in the world***.
> >     ***Not clinging***, he is ***not agitated***; being not agitated, he himself ***surely attains nirvana***.